# ElasticSearch 7.1.1 - can not start Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using regular (free) version of ElasticSearch 7.1.1 and tried to start Kibana `./bin/kibana` and getting error:

```
log   [19:51:16.108] [error][security] Error registering Kibana Privileges with Elasticsearch for kibana-.kibana: 
[cluster_block_exception] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];, with { suppressed={ 0={ type="cluster_block_exception" & reason="blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];" } 
& 1={ type="cluster_block_exception" & reason="blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];" } 
& 2={ type="cluster_block_exception" & reason="blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];" } } }
```

Tried as well:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices | awk '{ print $3 }' | sort | xargs -L 1 -I{} curl -s -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/\{\}/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
{"acknowledged":true}{"acknowledged":true}{"acknowledged":true}{"acknowledged":true}%
```

But did not help..

How to pass this error?

Comment: did you check the watermark and free disk space?

Comment: and please try to put "false" instead of null.